# Listing systray app in bash

Tags: bash, system-tray, xorg, systray

I would like to make a specific command for lemonbar or rofi/dmenu that could tell me applications which are minimized on systray, I looked on wmctrl and xdotool but none of those does the job.

Anyway to get that information with other command ?

Comment: Not really a bash question -- any answer you got would be a tool you could use from any other shell (or programming language with access to `execv`-family syscalls).

Comment: well because I didn't really knew which tags to select..

Comment: Hmm. Reading the lemonbar source, it doesn't look like it's implementing the [FreeDesktop systemtray specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/0.3/ar01s04.html). (Upstream X11 doesn't have any concept of a "system tray", so any implementation needs to depend on extensions and be specific to same).

Comment: i know lemonbar doesn't implement anything, that's why I'm looking for something to implement data directly myself.

Comment: So, which application *is* providing your tray (keeping mind again that it isn't a thing that X11 itself implements)? Or to come at it from a different perspective -- which desktop environment are you using? Which window manager?

Comment: I am running i3 so I have no systray app, but some apps like polybar provides a systray, and I saw freedesktop standards seems to manage systray.

Comment: My understanding is that if your window manager doesn't handle the messages setting up system tray icons, there's nowhere they get persisted/stored you can query -- they're just gone. Applications that want to set up a tray icon need to send a message to the manager implementing the protocol; if there isn't one, they can't do that, so that setup simply doesn't happen.

Comment: I understand what u mean. So the only solution is to provide a specific manager with X api.. I think..